# Accessing values of dictionary using string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` with three key/value pairs.

```
key1 - person object1 
key2 - person object2 
key3 - person object3
```

By comparing a string with the key in the dictionary, I need to retrieve the contents of the person object. How can I do this? Please help me. My code is:

```
NSArray *keys = [persondict allKeys];
    id key;
    for(int i= 0; i<[keys count]; ++i)
    {   key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
    }
    for(id key in persondict){
        if ([key isEqual:agentrefattr]){
            //how to get the person object here?
            [aperson setPhoneNumber:aperson.PhoneNumber];
            [aperson setEmailAddress:aperson.EmailAddress];
            [aPersonName setGivenName:aPersonName.GivenName];
            [aPersonName setSurname:aPersonName.Surname];
            [aperson setPersonName:aperson.PersonName];

            [self.agentarray insertObject:aperson atIndex:index];
            [self.agentnamearray insertObject:aPersonName atIndex:index];
            aperson = [agentarray objectAtIndex:index];
            aPersonName = [agentnamearray objectAtIndex:index];

            NSLog(@"att:%@",agentrefattr);
            NSLog(@"Email :%@",aperson.EmailAddress);
            NSLog(@"Phone :%@",aperson.PhoneNumber);
            NSLog(@"Given Name :%@",aperson.PersonName.GivenName);
            NSLog(@"SurName :%@",aperson.PersonName.Surname);
```

Please help me with some hints. I want to access the properties, `GivenName`, `Surname`, etc., in the person object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys in a dictionary are unique.  So if `agentrefattr` is a string representing a key, yuu will only ever have one object in the dictionary with that key, so there is no need for a loop at all.  Just do this:

```
aPerson = [personDict objectForKey: agentrefattr];
```

Comment: To be clear;  both for() loops in the original poster's code are completely pointless.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I tried that but the data in the last person object is only retrieved for all the keys. The kes are unique but the value is getting overwritten by the last value from my XML.

Comment: I had a mistake in my code. With the suggestion you gave it worked well.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

A much better design is using enumerateobjectsandkeyswithoption: using block:^(id obj,id key)